# Unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, unix

I've been asked to modify a bash script at my internship and since yesterday was the first time I started reading up on Bash syntax, I'm having a hard time figuring out a "syntax error: unexpected end of file" error. I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out.

The last part of the script is:

```
    echo "  " >>${MAILLOG}

    echo "Building CSAPI SDK" >>${MAILLOG}
        cd ${BuildsDIR}
        make sdk
    # Wait 3 minutes for the HDXs to reboot and SDK build to complete
    echo "Waiting for the HDXs to reboot and SDK build to complete..." >>${MAILLOG}
        sleep 180
    echo "Running PyUnit tests" >>${MAILLOG}
        cd Common/csapi/pyunit
        make test >>${TESTLOG} 2>&1

    TestReportLink=`mklink ${BUILDURL}/${1}/build/Common/csapi/pyunit/report.xml`
    TestLogLink=`mklink ${BUILDURL}/${1}/build/${1}.test.log`

    echo "Test report: ${TestReportLink}" >>${MAILLOG} 
    echo "Test log: ${TestLogLink}"  >>${MAILLOG} 
    # Wait 3 minutes for the tests to complete
        sleep 180
```

Comment: Do any of the MAILLOG/TESTLOG/other paths have spaces in them?

Comment: No, none of them have spaces.

Comment: Can we get some context for the error message? Does anything get printed out before it? Also, can you put the full script online and link to it?

Comment: Also, if you remove the lines you posted from the end of the script, does the error still occur? If so, it means the error isn't in what you posted. (You can use this technique to narrow down where the syntax error is)

Comment: A bunch of stuff get's printed, but all of that is from the echo's in the script, nothing out of the ordinary. Here is a link to script: http://www.2shared.com/document/aT7VjOCc/doCopperVenusbuild__1_.html?

Comment: That is absolutely the worst file sharing site I've ever seen.

Comment: @iman453: You can see a trace of what the script is doing by running it with `bash -x /path/to/script`. If you still can't solve your problem, try posting the full output of that.

Comment: @Gilles: There's already a `set -x` at the top of the script. See my answer.

Comment: For future reference, http://pastebin.com/ is a better way of posting lengthy scripts, build outputs, code samples, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On about line 129 of that script this appears:

```
    EOFBUILDFAILUREMSG
```

remove the leading white space from that line and your error message will go away.

That's the ending delimiter of a here document. You could leave in the leading white space if line 123 was changed to have the redirection operator as `<<-` and the white space consisted of only tabs (no spaces):

```
    cat <<-EOFBUILDFAILUREMSG >>${MAILLOG}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like noted in https://superuser.com/q/184861/48480, the mklink() replaces "/" with "\". e.g. `${BUILDURL}/${1}/build/${1}.test.log` gets replaced by something like `ausdatos01\\development\\mrahman\\projects\\builds\\autobuilder\\<source directory>\\build\\<source directory>.test.log`. Since you tagged the question being *NIX-related, this path might not exist. On first sight, it looks, like the script is written to work on a Windows host (e.g. in cygwin...).

What happens, if you change the mklink to

```
mklink () {
#    node="\\\\$1"
#    echo $node`echo $2|sed 's/\//\\\\/g'`
}
```